# Crystal Reports Null Handling

Tags: crystal-reports

If this is a duplicate I apologize, I wasn't able to find anything that was of help.

Also, I am new to Crystal Reports, so I may be missing something obvious...

I have a table with a column that may be either null, or contain certain values.

From what I can tell, we have this formula field that omits records based on certain criteria.

I need to modify this formula so that if the parameter I created is TRUE, it will allow the null values, if it is false it will ignore them.

Here is the code I am currently looking at:

```
 If (
 ({?AllowNulls} = True and isnull({Table.Name}))
 or (ucase({Table.Name}) IN ['ITEM1','ITEM2','MAC'])
 )
 and {Table.Type} = 2 
 and {Table.Inbound} = "PRIVATE" then 
 0
 else
 1
```

I have tried setting "Exceptions for Nulls" to "Default values for Nulls" and moved the logic around to different iterations, and nothing seems to work.

Here is the Record Selection code that uses the output from the Formula Field

```
{@OmitDialerprivates} = 1 and
(
If {?Direction} = "IN" Then
    {Table.Type} IN [2,4]
Else If {?Direction} = "OUT" Then
    {Table.Type} IN [1,3]
Else If {?CallDirection} = "BOTH" Then
    {Table.Type} IN [1,2,3,4]
) and
(
If {?Ext} = "ALL" or {?Extension} = "" Then
    True
Else
    {Table.Ext} = {?Ext}
) and
(
If IsDate({?StartDate}) Then
    {Table.DateTime} >= CDate({?StartDate})
Else
    True
) and
(
If IsDate({?EndDate}) Then
    {Table.DateTime} < CDate({?EndDate})+1
Else
    True
)
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you explain more on this ``if the parameter I created is TRUE, it will allow the null values``

Comment: If table.name is null, it will either include all of them, or exclude all of them based on if I have "Exceptions for Nulls" or "Default values for Nulls" selected. I would like to include the null values when the user selects TRUE for AllowNulls, and exclude them when they select FALSE for AllowNulls

Comment: The way you have it now, the `{?AllowNulls}` parameter will only affect whether or not the record should be considered "Private"...but you are explicitly NOT including private records in your record selection formula. Is that what you're intending? From the wording of your question it seems like this is the issue.

Comment: No, I want to include all of the nulls, not exclude them.